# Update user meta after order status completed - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've read a variety of question on this topic, however, I am struggling to update the users meta after a woocommerce order has been completed.

I have doubled(triple) checked the product_ids in the `if` statement and I've done a number of test payments and also toggled the order status to see if the user meta updates. I come here as a last resort.

I've even manually entered in the `$user_id` and `product_id` to the function in a process of elimination, however I cannot get it to `update_user_meta`

Any tips to help me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
/**
 * Update usermeta when the order processed woocommerce
 */
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'open_assessment_after_payment');

function open_assessment_after_payment($order_id) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    }

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;

    if($product_id == '240') {

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'open_1', true );

    } elseif($product_id == '238') {

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'open_2', true );

    } elseif($product_id == '239') {

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'open_3', true );

    }
}
```

Comment: try echo / var_dump your variables and then exit immed after. the code looks ok except it will only work for the last $items (you overwrite $productid on ea loop) and only if the items = 1 of the values you have provided.

Comment: I simply needed to use 'true' instead of true, `update_user_meta( $user_id, 'open_1', 'true' );` silly me.